# Geoprocessing tool for finding specific point within polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, geoprocessing, point

I have a ArcGIS task and cannot find a solution. 
I try to find a certain point within a polygon (see picture). This example is handmade and I need a geoprocessing solution 
[image: Point in Polygon]

I point I try to get is the one that is furthest away from the borders of the polygon, but not only from the outline of the polygon (this would be centroid), but ALSO from the inner line. Thus this would be the point around which I could draw/buffer the biggest circle around within the polygon (without touching the borders of the polygon).
I hope my explanation was understandable.

Comment: Perhaps look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279478/largest-circle-inside-a-non-convex-polygon

Comment: also look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2614/for-every-point-distance-to-nearest-polygon-of-type-x (second answer listed) there's a tool called "Point distance" that seems to be what you're after.

Comment: @user1269942 [That tool](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/2617/115) sounds like it looks for the nearest polygon that the point is outside of rather than maximizing the size of a circle from within.

Comment: @PolyGeo in the 'notes' section, it says to convert the polygons to polylines, then it'll give distance to boundaries.

Comment: @user1269942 I'll re-phrase - that tool starts with a known point whereas this question is about determining the XY location of the point that determines the largest circle that can be drawn inside the polygon.

Comment: @PolyGeo ah, good to clarify that, thanks.  So, "for every open region, find the set of points that maximizes the radius of a circle that can be drawn at that point (or points) with only tangentially touching the nearby polygons".  Tricky problem because in the drawing, there looks to be one unique possible radius but a segment of possible points (infinite).  Depending on the desired accuracy, one could iterate through all points on the corresponding rasterized representation.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments. Last two responses are what I am still trying to solve. For my case it would not matter if I find one or several point having the same radius. A good example can be seen here: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1729&t=257685 there it is the third post showing the states of the U.S. with the largest possible interior circle. But still i couldn´t manage to do it even with an simple example.